# Foreign Key relationship between two columns in one table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm building a database table representing a 'note' that has a parent-child relationship in two of it's columns, like so:

```
ID           INT(10) PK NOT NULL UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTOINCREMENT  -- Primary key
parent_ID    INT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL                 -- References Primary key
username     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
information  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
comment      VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
```

where `username` is a foreign key to a `user` table and is the username of the person who wrote the note, `information` is the information contained in the note and `comment` is what `username` added. `comment` will always have something in it, and is not necessarily the same as the previous user.

The concept is that someone can "copy" a note and have their own comments, and say "I got this note from xxx", hence the parent-child relationship. A bit like sharing in facebook, perhaps.

How do I correctly form the parent_ID column? Should I use an identifying relationship; which sides are mandatory?
I figure this has to be a 1-to-Many relationship since five people can copy the same note.

I expect there to be more copying than creating new notes, so there will be a relatively small number of `NULL`'s in the records, but to get rid of nulls entirely should I apply a `NOT NULL` constraint and simply make the default parent `0` with an essentially meaningless record at `ID 0` and take note of this in the software?

Is this even the correct way? Should I employ a two-table system with:

```
ID          INT(10)      PK
information VARCHAR(256)
orig_user   VARHCAR(30)  FK  -- Potentially
```

and

```
ID          INT(10)      PK FK
username    VARCHAR(30)  PK FK
comment     VARCHAR(256)
```

Which eliminates any possible `NULL`'s by definiton?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use an identifying relationship

No, only `ID` should be in PK since it **alone** is unique. Also, a root (parent-less) note will have a NULL `parent_ID` and NULLs cannot be in PK.

> I figure this has to be a 1-to-Many relationship since five people can copy the same note.

Correct. It's also a tree, since there can be multiple levels of copying.

> ... should I apply a NOT NULL constraint and simply make the default parent 0 with an essentially meaningless record at ID 0 and take note of this in the software?

No need, FK would still be enforced on 0 and you'd need a "dummy" row just to satisfy it, as you already noted. FK ignores NULLs, so just put a NULL in the root note's `parent_ID`.

> Should I employ a two-table system...

This doesn't model the same thing. It just allows you to connect to the original user, but not original note.

A *different* two-table design would be viable if a single note could have multiple parents, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

> Which eliminates any possible NULL's by definiton?

You seem very intent on eliminating NULLs. Any reason for that?

---

All in all, you should store notes in just one table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE note (
    ID           INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_ID    INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    username     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    information  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    comment      VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_ID) REFERENCES note (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES `user` (username)
);
```

Comment: I thought `NULL`s were generally bad, as it was "wasted space" and should be normalised out, but thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Modern dbs are very good at not using space for nulls, particularly if they are on the right side of the table.

Comment: @Sinagog _"I thought NULLs were generally bad"_ It is true that 3-valued logic of NULLs can be [unintuitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Controversy) and is not implemented consistently throughout SQL, but NULLs are still very useful in practical databases. _"as it was wasted space"_ A NULL will typically require **less** storage than a "special" value such as 0 you mentioned. On some DBMSes it might require as little as one bit (!) of space (I think it's 1-2 bytes on MySQL/InnoDB).